Given $\nu$ a Radon measure on $Y\subset X$, $\mu(E) := \nu(E \cap Y )$ is not necessarily a Radon measure on $X$ if $Y\subset X$ not closed
Problem: Let $X$ be an LCH (locally compact Hausdorff) space, and $Y$ a closed subset of $X$. Show that if $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $Y$ , then $\nu(E) := \mu(E \cap Y )$ defines a Radon measure $\nu$ on $X$ (proved). Also demonstrate that $Y$ being closed is needed here, by giving an example where $Y$ is not closed and the corresponding $\nu$ is not Radon.
My effort: I have proved that if $Y$ is closed then $\mu$ is a Radon measure. Indeed, the fact that $Y$ is closed is used in the proof, mostly because we need the fact that if $K\subseteq X$ is a compact set in $X$ then $Y\cap K$ is compact (both in $X$ and in $Y$ with relative topology). However, I don't know how to construct the counter-example. Can anyone help me with that?
Definition of Radon measure: Radon measure is a Borel measure that is 1. finite on compact sets; 2. inner regular on open sets 3. Outer regular on all Borel sets.

It would be a good idea in general to include some definitions of the relevant terms and symbols in your question, to increase the likelihood of engagement from others, as it removes some barriers, and shows that you put in some effort, and at least know the relevant definitions. In this particular case, I would recommend defining (or at least expanding) "LCH space" and explaining what $\mu$ is

presumably also you meant in the last paragraph that you have shown $\nu$ to be Radon? It seems like $\mu$ is the given measure

@Carlyle Thank you for your advice. Yes, I mixed up with $\mu$ and $\nu$ when typing the problem, and now it should be well formulated. Also, I add the definition of LCH space and Radon measure.

Let $Y = (-1, 1) \subset \mathbb{R} = X$. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to (-1, 1)$ be a homeomorphism (for example, $f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x)$), and let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mu = f_\ast(\lambda)$ is a Radon measure on $Y = (-1, 1)$, but the corresponding $\nu$ is not a Radon measure because it is not locally finite. (For example, $\nu([-1, 1]) = \infty$.)

$\nu$ in this case is also not outer regular, since $\nu({1}) = 0$ but any open interval containing $1$ has infinite $\nu$-measure. Though it is inner regular on open sets. It is in fact not hard to show that $\nu$ is always inner regular on open sets whenever $\mu$ is.
